# All new layer si transparent

Tags: photoshop, transparent, layer

I have a problem with photoshop. I don't know what I did, but now when I create a new text, add a new image or else new all layer is transparent.
That problem is on only one project. Opacity and Fill are set to 100%[image]
How can I fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably set the opacity of the whole group of those layers (called 44), check that!

Comment: Thanks, Antal Gyuri!
I did not know about opacity of group